# V5 Messaging Provider with ListenerPort

Tags: java, queue, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

I configured a queue and a QueueConnectionFactory using the V5 Messaging provider in WebSphere Application Server 6.1.

I also have a *ListenerPort* configured for this destination.

It throws an exception when I try to connect to this queue using the queue connection factory or when the Message Listener listening to this ListenerPort starts up.

```
 javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager 
 for 'localhost:WAS_Node01_server1'
```

and the nested exception is

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2059
MQJE011: Socket connection attempt refused
```

Can someone please point me to what possibily could have gone wrong in configuring the queue and queue connection factory?

Comment: Any number of things.  The 2059 can mean the CF is pointing to the wrong host, that the QMgr is not up, that the QMgr is up but on a different port, etc.  Can you provide the CF definition and whether the QMgr you are trying to connect to is local, remote, etc.?

Comment: Actually I don't have an MQ or a QueueManager. I was trying to use and test ListenerPort configured to a queue on V5 Messaging Provider. I think I misunderstood the V5 Messaging provider for a standalone Messaging provider.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the WebSphere MQ transport is being used.  Per the clarification in your comments, no queue manager is present so a 2059 is expected.  It will be necessary to configure a WAS messaging Engine to provide the native transport or to point to a queue manager.